# Getting an AD password via code

Tags: active-directory

I am thinking of coding my own password manager with AD-integration. However, is it possible to "Get" an AD password? How do the commercial tools do this?

Thanks

Comment: If they allowed this, it would be horribly insecure.  Also, you should review your previous questions and choose some correct answers (as appropriate).  People don't typically answer questions posted by folks with low accept rates because it means they don't get the reputation bonus for their efforts.

Comment: I know it'd be very insecure but then how do other tools do it?

Comment: "Other tools" do not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot retrieve the password unless it was set to "Store password using reversible encryption."